# Invariant measure on Graff(2,1)

Tags: measure-theory, vector-bundles

What is the invariant measure on Graff$(2,1)$ the set of all straight lines in $\mathbb R^2$?

I tried looking at it this way:

One is aware that Graff$(2,1)$ can be identified with the canonical bundle over $\mathbb RP^1$. Is this measure something to do with measures on vector bundles?

I need an answer or a reference to look for an answer in.

Comment: What group do you want the measure to be invariant under?  The affine group?

Comment: As per the source suggested in the answer, the invariance is under isometries of the plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](http://webbuild.knu.ac.kr/~yjsuh/proceedings/12th/%5b2%5d08Prowork_Zhou_1-2.pdf).
Also there is the disscussion of the general questions on invariant measures of this type